# RPM install file conflict from previous install

Tags: linux, rhel, rpm, rpm-spec

I am getting install failure due to file conflicts. I am facing this issue only on Red Hat Linux 7. Same spec file works on Ubuntu and other Linux distributions.

I tried putting echo on `%pre`, `%post`, `%preun` and `%postun` sections but I never reached those messages. I tried `%dump` at the beginning of spec file which also didn't print anything.
How do I trace the spec file execution?

```
%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
@CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX@/sbin/MyExe
@CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX@/share/doc/@CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME@/myconf.conf
@CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX@/share/doc/@CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME@/README
%if @IS_RHEL7@
/etc/systemd/system/myoverride.conf
%endif
```

Error during install:

```
Preparing packages...
    file /etc/systemd/system/myoverride.conf from install of mypackage-5.0.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mypackage-4.11.1.x86_64
    file /usr/sbin/myexe from install of mypackage-5.0.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mypackage-4.11.1.x86_64
```

Comment: What method of installation are you using? I mean `rpm` or `yum`?

Comment: I am using rpm, I do not want to use -U option for upgrade or --force or --replaceFiles etc. I want it to handle the upgrade itself.

Answer (score 18):

you cannot install twice the same rpm. Therefore if you want to install a newer version of the same rpm (mypackage in your case); you need to use the `-U | --upgrade` option. Typical usage of `rpm` goes like this:

```
rpm -Uvh mypackage-<new-version>.rpm
```

- `-U` : upgrade mypackage to this version
- `-vh` : nice display of progress.

Comment: Both rpms have different version of the config and installer, they include changes in configuration file and exe. I need to upgrade both with this install.

Comment: If you want to install both rpms you'll need to rename one of them because you cannot install two rpms with the same name